# Java install on Windows

Tags: java, windows

I have installed the Java JDK (jdk1.8.0_161) on a Windows Server 2012 box.

Created the path JAVA_HOME path to the location of install.

When I run `java -version` from the PowerShell, it returns the version info but in red error text.. (It seems to return the info fine from the command prompt).

Is this an issue? I'm trying to run Maven and getting issues and looking to resolve root issues before digging deeper.

Thanks

```
java -version
java : java version "1.8.0_161"
At line:1 char:1
+ java -version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (java version "1.8.0_161":String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with powershell. What happens when you run java -version from cmd and what happens when you run mvn -version from cmd?

Comment: Just to update, installed on my windows 10 machine and getting a no error out put of:

 java -version
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

Comment: running from the command returns no errors..

Answer (score 0):

> When i run java -version from the powershell it returns the version info but in red error text.. (It seems to return the info fine from the command prompt).
>
> Is this an issue?

I don't think so.

The behavior of `java -version` is unusual.  Where most applications write version information to standard output, the tools in the Oracle Java tool chains write the information to standard error.

With a typical shell, you don't notice this unless you redirect `java -version` output.

Apparently, powershell is using colors to distinguish output coming from standard error.  If this is the explanation, then it is harmless.

Comment: Hi Stephen, 

My only worry is that it returns a normal output from my machine. but errors with output on the server.

Comment: If you are worried, do some experiments with redirection on powershell to verify what I said.  I am not familiar with powershell syntax, and I don't have a Windows machine to play with.